# Is there a way to convert from string to integer while sorting in python using itemgetter or lambda?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a dictionary that has all ids as string (id_categ, id_macrocateg, id_microcateg). I don't want to iterate all the dict to convert them in integer and after sort them. I want to know if there is a way with itemgetter or lambda to convert all ids to int while sorting.

An example of a  list of dictionaries could be this (for real, the list could change dynamically):

```
          l_dictt = [
            {'id_categ': '1', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '1'},
            {'id_categ': '1', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '111'},
            {'id_categ': '14', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '35'},
            {'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '9'},
            {'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '19'},
            {'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '26'},
            {'id_categ': '2', 'id_macrocateg': '50', 'id_microcateg': '554'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '4'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '16'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '17'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '20'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '21'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '24'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '31'},
            {'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '11'},
            {'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '12'},
            {'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '13'},
            {'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '10'},
            {'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '27'},
            {'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '28'},
            {'id_categ': '30', 'id_macrocateg': '6', 'id_microcateg': '112'},
            {'id_categ': '30', 'id_macrocateg': '6', 'id_microcateg': '112'}]
```

the output I want is:

```
            l_dictt = [
            {'id_categ': '1', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '1'},
            {'id_categ': '1', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '111'},
            {'id_categ': '14', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '35'},
            {'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '9'},
            {'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '19'},
            {'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '26'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '4'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '16'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '17'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '20'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '21'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '24'},
            {'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '31'},
            {'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '11'},
            {'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '12'},
            {'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '13'},
            {'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '10'},
            {'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '27'},
            {'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '28'},
            {'id_categ': '30', 'id_macrocateg': '6', 'id_microcateg': '112'},
            {'id_categ': '30', 'id_macrocateg': '6', 'id_microcateg': '112'},
            {'id_categ': '2', 'id_macrocateg': '50', 'id_microcateg': '554'}]
```

if those 3 keys were integers, as I wanted sort first by id_macrocateg, after by id_categ and at the end id_microcateg, I could do this:

```
  for dictt in sorted(l_dictt, key=itemgetter('id_macrocateg', 'id_categ', 'id_microcateg'):
     print(dictt)
```

But as the are strings I cannot do that.

I have tried:

```
    from operator import itemgetter
    for dictt in sorted(l_dictt, key=lambda x: int(itemgetter("id_macrocateg, id_categ, id_microcateg")(x))):

           print(dictt)
```

and also this:

```
  from operator import itemgetter
  for dictt in sorted(l_dictt, key=lambda x: int(itemgetter("id_macrocateg")(x)),int(itemgetter("id_categ")(x))),int(itemgetter(("id_microcateg")(x))):
     print(dictt)
```

Comment: `lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.values()))`?

Comment: `itemgetter` would be a lot nicer in this case if Python supported function composition, e.g. `sorted(l_dictt, key=int∘itemgetter("id_macrocateg"))`. IMO an operator is really necessary to get the full benefit; `key=compose(int, itemgetter("id_macrocateg"))` still seems too verbose.

Comment: @SayandipDutta That assumes (as is safe in this case, but not in general), that every value in the `dict` *can* be converted to an `int`, whether it's necessary or not. It might also be expensive to make a large number of unnecessary `int` calls.

Comment: But most importantly, it sorts on `id_categ` before `id_macrocateg`.

Comment: Or for multiple columns, `key=partial(map, int)∘itemgetter("id_macrocateg", "id_categ", "id_microcateg")`.

Comment: @chepner at the time the question did not include the expected output, I assumed it was to be sorted by multiple keys.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third attempt is just missing some parentheses to ensure that all three calls to `int` are part of the body of the `lambda` expression.

```
from operator import itemgetter
for dictt in sorted(l_dictt, key=lambda x: (int(itemgetter("id_macrocateg")(x)),
                                            int(itemgetter("id_categ")(x))),
                                            int(itemgetter(("id_microcateg")(x))):
    print(dictt)
```

though `itemgetter` really just gets in the way here.

```
for dictt in sorted(l_dictt, key=lambda x: (int(l_dictt["id_macrocateg"]),
                                            int(l_dictt["id_categ"]),
                                            int(l_dictt["id_microcateg"]):
    print(dictt)
```

You could use `map` with `itemgetter`, similar to your second attempt:

```
from operator import itemgetter


# Splitting up for readability
getter = itemgetter("id_macrocateg", "id_categ", "id_microcateg")

for dictt in sorted(l_dictt, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, getter(x))):
    print(dictt)
```

though again a generator expression with a list of keys may be simpler:

```
keys = ("id_macrocateg", "id_categ", "id_microcateg")

for dictt in sorted(l_dictt, key=lambda x: [int(x[k]) for k in keys]):
```

(using a list only because there is no tuple comprehension; lists and tuples sort in the same fashion.)

Answer (score 1):

Answer after updating question:

Now, you want the list to be sorted on id_macrocateg, id_categ and id_microcateg, so we get it by:

```
sorted(l_dictt, key=lambda x: x['id_macrocateg'].zfill(10)+x['id_categ'].zfill(10)+x['id_microcateg'].zfill(10))
```

Here I assumed that the maximum number of digits could be 10 digits '9999999999', and surely we can update if we need.

The results

```
{'id_categ': '1', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '1'}
{'id_categ': '1', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '111'}
{'id_categ': '14', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '35'}
{'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '9'}
{'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '19'}
{'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '26'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '4'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '16'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '17'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '20'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '21'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '24'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '31'}
{'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '11'}
{'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '12'}
{'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '13'}
{'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '10'}
{'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '27'}
{'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '28'}
{'id_categ': '30', 'id_macrocateg': '6', 'id_microcateg': '112'}
{'id_categ': '30', 'id_macrocateg': '6', 'id_microcateg': '112'}
{'id_categ': '2', 'id_macrocateg': '50', 'id_microcateg': '554'}
```

Initial answer before updating the question:

You can sort that dictionary by the value of `id_categ` while keeping its values untouched as follows:

```
for dictt in sorted(l_dictt, key=lambda x: int(x['id_categ'])):
    print(dictt)
```

The results

```
{'id_categ': '1', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '1'}
{'id_categ': '1', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '111'}
{'id_categ': '2', 'id_macrocateg': '50', 'id_microcateg': '554'}
{'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '11'}
{'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '12'}
{'id_categ': '10', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '13'}
{'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '10'}
{'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '27'}
{'id_categ': '12', 'id_macrocateg': '2', 'id_microcateg': '28'}
{'id_categ': '14', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '35'}
{'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '9'}
{'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '19'}
{'id_categ': '19', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '26'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '4'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '16'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '17'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '20'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '21'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '24'}
{'id_categ': '21', 'id_macrocateg': '1', 'id_microcateg': '31'}
{'id_categ': '30', 'id_macrocateg': '6', 'id_microcateg': '112'}
{'id_categ': '30', 'id_macrocateg': '6', 'id_microcateg': '112'}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that the id_macrocateg is nor ordered. I want to order first by id_macrocateg, second by id_categ and at the end by id_microcateg. I edited the question to explain better what I need.

Comment: You have modified your question after I published the answer.